# UTC Date time string to Zoned DateTime using NodaTime

Tags: datetime, timezone, nodatime

I need to convert a UTC `DateTime` string to a `ZonedDateTime`.

The UTC `DateTime` strings can only be one pattern`(M/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt)` as only this format is supported in a SharePoint `DateTime` type column.

Assuming that `(5/28/2013 1:00:00 PM)` as my UTC time, how can I convert it into `ZonedDateTime`? I am currently using the below code to obtain the `ZonedDateTime`.

```cs
var dateTimeZone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb[zoneID];
var inst = Instant.FromUtc(year, month, day, hour, minute);
ZonedDateTime dz = new ZonedDateTime(inst, dateTimeZone);
```

The above code needs the `year`, `month`, `day`, `hour`, and `minute` as `int` values.  Is there an easier way to obtain the `ZonedDateTime` directly from the UTC string?

Answer (score 4):

I think you are confused about your source data.  SharePoint doesn't store strings for dates.  It stores them as `DateTime` types.  They are at UTC, but they aren't strings.

If you have a string representation, then at some point in your code you did a [`.ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k494fzbf.aspx) or similar, and it picked up the default [`"G"` format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx#GeneralDateLongTime).

So you should just be able to use:

```cs
var inst = Instant.FromDateTimeUtc(yourDateTime);
var dz = new ZonedDateTime(inst, dateTimeZone);
```

The other option you have is to use `DateTimeOffset` fields in SharePoint instead of UTC `DateTime` fields.  [Read here](http://itblog.wolthaus.net/2011/09/sharepoint-stores-dates-in-utc-time/).  Then you can use `Instant.FromDateTimeOffset()`.

Comment: You are right Matt, the sharepoint does not store the values as string. I have a small query, is it safe to convert the datetime string which I am getting to DateTime type using DateTime.Parse, and then go ahead and use your code to obtain the Zone based DateTime value?

Comment: No, its not safe..  Parsing can introduce locale specifics.  Keep it as a DateTime.

Comment: Matt, I found out the reason why we were getting the UTC datetime as string. Sharepoint stores the values in UTC, but displays the values stored in current server timezone. Also, when we read the values of a list item in the format of a datatable/ xml, due to serialization, the UTC gets converted to server timezone's value.

Comment: Ok, so you aren't getting the data directly from the database, but from an XML that SharePoint is generating that you can't control, right?  Can you post a small bit of what the date looks like in that XML?  One would hope that they use a standard format like ISO8601 and not a culture-specific display format.